# sort_values vs order by and when and why should I use which

Tags: sql, pandas

This is mainly in the scope of jupyter notes and queries in pandas(i'm very new to both) . I noticed that when I write a query where I need the dataframe in a certain order I do:

```
df = pd.read_sql("select date, count(*) as count from "+tableName+" group by date" ,conn").sort_values(['date'].ascending=False)
```

My friends who are much more experienced than me do :

```
df = pd.read_sql("select date, count(*) as count from "+tableName+" group by date order by date",conn")
```

The results are the same but I couldnt get an answer about why/when I would use **order by** over **sort_values**

Comment: Did you try timing the two solutions?

Comment: not really as I guess I never ran into anything large enough where the answer using either makes any noticeable difference. Is there I way I can tack on the timing for execution in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, both achieve the same output. The difference in is *where* the sorting operation takes place. In the first case, `sort_values()` is a pandas function which you've chained onto the first `read_sql()` function. This means that your Python engine is executing the sort *after* it retrieves the data from the database connection. This is equivalent to doing something like:

```python
df = pd.read_sql("select date, count(*) as count from "+tableName+" group by date" ,conn)  
df = df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False) #sorting done in python environment, not by the database
```

The second method performs the sorting in the database, so the python environment doesn't sort anything. The key here is to remember that you're basically composing a SQL statement and running it using Python pandas.

Whether or not you should put the burden of sorting on the database or on your machine that's running the python environment depends. If this is a very busy production database you might not want to run expensive sorting operations but simply retrieve the data and perform all operations locally using pandas. Alternatively, if the database is for casual use or non-critical, then in this case it makes sense to just sort the results and before loading the data into pandas.

Update:
To reinforce the notion that SQL engine driven (server side, or db driven) sorting isn't necessarily always the most optimal thing to do, please read [**this article**](https://medium.com/carwow-product-engineering/sql-vs-pandas-how-to-balance-tasks-between-server-and-client-side-9e2f6c95677) which has some interesting profiling stats and common scenarios of when to load the db with data manipulation operations vs. when to do it "locally".

Comment: @chowpay This answer just mentions where the sorting takes place. I think you already know that. It does not explain why one is better than the other. I don't think it really answers the question.

Comment: @coldspeed I figure that the one is better than the other based on this comment:  "Whether or not you should put the burden of sorting on the database or on your machine" I actually didn't notice that when I do sort_values it was local machine because in my use case jupyter is installed on an instance we all access.

Comment: @chowpay I've added a link to the answer to reinforce what I've said in the latter half. As a data scientist who deals with TBs of data everyday, I cringe when junior engineers run expensive sorting operations on the DB when they could just as well get away with it in their local/dev machines. Without a comparison of sorting algorithms used, or firm profiling stats that compare performance of a specific case, it is simply not the case that SQL engines should always be used for sort. I hope that coldspeed will consider undoing his/her downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few reasons here:

1. **Performance**
   Many, many hours of effort have gone into tuning the code that runs SQL commands. SQL is *fast*, and I'm willing to bet it is going to be faster to sort with the SQL engine than with pandas.
2. **Maintainability**
   If, for example, you determine that you do not need the result sorted tomorrow, then you can simply change the query string without having to change your code. This is particularly useful if you are passing the query to some function which runs it for you.
3. **Aesthetics**
   As a programmer with good design sense, surely the second method should appeal to you. Segmenting logic into separate pieces is definitely a recipe for bad design.

Comment: oh ic, so because its .sort_value.. this means SQL is not doing the sorting and pandas is doing the sorting right? (in response to your #1 *edit* was just answered by ash). #2 sounds like it would be a case for using .sort_values right? meaning if the query already ran and is now in a DF I don't have to run it again I can just sort it and assign the sorrted DF to a new variable. (let me know if I'm mis reading your answer) thanks

Comment: @chowpay I reordered the list items. But you are right.

Comment: Stumbled over this myself just now as I was curious about whether there was a crossing point where disk speed would be limiting vs. pulling straight into memory. The most surprising finding was the default settings for postgres linked in the other article; the buffer for sorting is _tiny_